# How to write Nested sub queries in Sequelize

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I am new to Sequelize and stuck at building one query,i tried with the Postgres query it works but not able to build the same query in sequelize
Below is the postgres query

`SELECT count, createdDate FROM (
    select id,COUNT(*) as count, to_char("createdAt", 'DD-MM-YYYY') as createdDate from public.audit
WHERE "createdAt" >= '2020-02-15' AND "createdAt"<= '2020-02-27' group by id,createddate) as a 
group by count,createdDate`

This query works fine

Below is the Sequelize query that i have formed so far

```
{
  attributes:[
    'id',
    [Sequelize.literal('to_char("audit"."createdAt", \'DD-MM-YYYY\')'),'createdDate'], 
    [Sequelize.fn('COUNT','*'),'count']
  ],
  where: {
  createdAt:{ [Op.between]:['2020-02-15','2020-02-27']}
  },
    group:[
      'id',
      'createdDate'],
  raw : true , 
  nest : true
```

}

This query gives me count  by user id but now i am not able to group by count and date

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I have not understood the purpose of query that you want to develop. Irrespective of the value of `createdDate` the value of `count` will always be 1 since you have included `id` in the group statement of the inner query.

If you are looking out for some syntax, please refer the following code -

```
  const companyDetails = Company.count({
    attributes: ['id', 'createdAt'],
    where: {
      createdAt: { [op.between]: ['2019-02-15', '2020-02-27'] }
    },
    group: ['createdAt']
  });
```